# Is there a way to alias fields within a SOLR collection when querying with SOLRj?

Tags: solr, solrj

When querying SOLR in HTTP, fields within a collection can be aliased, but I can't seem to find the same functionality in SOLRj. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

it should work just like in the HTTP call:

```
query.setParam('fl', 'field1,myalias:aliasedfield');
```

did you try this?